# Sqlite3 autocomplete query?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, autocomplete, sqlite

I have an `SQLite3` file which contain student **full-name** "that mean it will be more than 1 word at least 4" and **students mark** "grad".

In UI I have `UITextField` work as "`search bar`" and `UITableView` when the user start change the value for the textField In async Task I execute fitch query from the database based on student full name and update the table when data is available so the table will be up to data each time the user change the value for the textField.

and here come the problem , there is to many cases for search/query :

1- The user enter single word.// he looking for student have this name Or it could be family name. in this case the query will be :

```
SELECT grade,name FROM students where name LIKE 'Adam%' OR name LIKE '% Adam' Limit 20 OFFSET 20
```

2- The user enter double word.// he looking for student by his/her first name and family name Or he enter first name and the second name . in this case the query will be :

```
SELECT grade,name FROM students where name LIKE 'Ahmad Rami%' OR name LIKE 'Ahmad % Rami%' Limit 20 OFFSET 20
```

3- The user keep entering text he enter the full name in this case no problem.

the problem is in first case if user start enter the family name "single word" the first query will execute but no result will appear until he write the full word for family name because there is no "%" after the "% Adam" but if we put "%" after it this will return wrong result in case the user meant first nam.

**EX:**

**"Adam Jon Mike Smith"**

**"Jon Adam Maikel Anglo"**

**"Jims Alin Rafiel Gorden"**

If the user enter "A" ==result==> Adam.....smith & jon ada.... Anglo // both of then appear because the **first name** of "Adam" and the **last Name** for "Jon" start with "A".
but in my case just Adam appear. 
if we change the query by adding the "%" at the end ,and the user enter "A" ===> "**Jims**" will appear in the result as will which I don't wanna it to appear

Answer (score 1):

You will have a hard time if you want a query to know the user's intention. The best you can get is to produce halfway intuitive results. Thus if  is the string entered by the user, you can search for '%' or '% %', adhering to the rule that the entered string must be the start of at least one of the words in the name string. Without an extra notation you can't distinguish this intention from the wish of searching for first names only.

From your question I derive that the different words within the name string have different meanings. Sometimes a word is regarded part of the first name (Adam both in "Jon Adam" and "Adam Jon") sometimes not (Alin in "Jims Alin").
You won't be able to distinguish these different meanings within a program without providing a huge knowledge base.

The solution to this problem is to tell your database which kind of meaning the words have. E.g. FirstName, MiddleName, LastName. Then you can specifically search for first or last names, disregarding the middle name.

Of course your users will have to tell which parts of the names have to be considered as first, middle or last names. From a computers point of view 'kjghlgkh' would be a perfect first name. But I very doubt that this "name" is indeed used as a first name somewhere on this world. Computers just do what they are told to do, they don't understand what they do. (OK, some AI projects give astonishing results, but that requires a kind of program and a knowledge base that isn't justified here).

Since I wanted to add some more remarks, I deleted my comment and posted it as an answer.